# How to exclude notifications outside the trunk using post-commit hook with VisualSVNServerHooks.exe?

Tags: svn, visualsvn-server, svn-hooks

We currently use an SVN hook (below) that sends email notification on every commit in the repository.  I am looking for a way to limit notifications only to changes that occur in the trunk, excluding tags/branches/etc.  Is there a way to create a limit like this using [VisualSVNServerHooks.exe](http://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00018/)?

Current:

```
"%VISUALSVN_SERVER%\bin\VisualSVNServerHooks.exe" ^
commit-notification "%1" -r %2 ^
--from server@email.com --to emaillist@company.com ^
--smtp-server smtp.company.com
```

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The feature will be implemented in upcoming VisualSVN Server 2.6.0.

You can also check this QA thread that has a batch script code that will help you:
[Post-commit hook that performs an action only if commit affects the specific path](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11521100/761095).