# VisualSVN Server Post commit hook a specific path

Tags: svn, visualsvn-server, post-commit-hook

How to do a post commit hook checkout a particular svn path checked in.

Right now I am only able to checkout when any file in the repository path is committed.
But how to add filter to check only the particular path(/Mobile/Node/trunk) in the repository is committed.

Do I need to do the filter in pre-commit hook?

Comment: Any solution for fixing this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution in the below link and it worked. 
[Why is my post-commit hook conditional statement not working when I check to see if a particular branch was committed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19426757/why-is-my-post-commit-hook-conditional-statement-not-working-when-i-check-to-see)

```
svnlook dirs-changed %1 -r %2 | findstr /b /i "branches/dev"

IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 (
    pushd <path-to-working-copy>
    svn update --username <repo-username> --password <repo-password>
)
```

in the place of "branches/dev". I replaced with my path "/Mobile/Node/trunk"