# Branch wise Post-Commit hook in svn

Tags: batch-file, curl, jenkins, svn, post-commit-hook

I have created CI using SVN(windows), Jenkins and Chef.

One of my project currently gets polled in Jenkins from post-commit hook and code from Trunk gets uploaded to local server using Chef. Now we have UAT server on Azure and we need to upload code only once or twice a week. So will create a branch UAT and when developer wants to upload code to UAT Server, he will merge the trunk to UAT branch.

I will create a different Job in Jenkins and would trigger it from post-commit hook. Creating another job would get me another `CURL` command.

Now how do I call that particular `CURL` command from my post commit hook if UAT Branch got check-in/merge by developer.

Below is my `post-commit.bat`

```
SET REPOS=%1  
SET REV=%2  
SET SVNLOOK="C:\Program Files\VisualSVN Server\bin\svnlook.exe" 
SET PROJECT=PROJECT_NAME

curl "http://10.0.0.16:8080/job/PROJECT_NAME/build?token=123" // For Local-server
```

I'm not that good in coding so not sure if I should be using IF-ELSE or something else. And do I implement that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19495885/960558

Comment: Thanks will update if that worked for me.